# Netty: Event Loop Group and custom events

Tags: netty

Can i use netty event group to execute custom task? I require same functionality as of socket channel, that is i want to register my object with event-loop and  execute it on a particular thread again and again?

Comment: Add some code to illustrate what you are trying to do

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can do this. It's as easy as obtaining the `EventLoop` of the `Channel` and then use any of the provided `ScheduledExecutorService` methods that it implements. That said you need to ensure you not do any blocking calls in these scheduled tasks as otherwise you will block the `EventLoop` and no I/O can happen on the `EventLoop` until the task completes (which will affect all `Channel`s that use this `EventLoop`).

For example this is how you would execute a task on the EventLoop:

```
EventLoop loop = channel.eventLoop();
loop.execute(() -> {
    // Do something.
});
```